# MySQL select with different collation

Tags: mysql, collation

MySQL5.5

As I understand, collations are sets of rules to sort and compare strings,
they allow for example to consider `'Mane'` the same as `'Manè'`.
To me a collation makes sense only in the context of a comparison of two text strings.

I have a table with `latin1` charset and `latin1_swedish_ci` collation

```
CREATE TABLE `swedish` (
  `c` char(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

engine, charset and collation are given constraints.

```
insert into swedish values ('Bar'), ('Bär'), ('Ber'), ('Bêr'), ('Yac'), ('Yaç');
```

I need to do a case- and accent-insensitive search with ASCII search values, I would like to use the collation `latin1_german1_ci` which treats those 3 couples as the same.

I've seen in the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-collate.html) how to do this

```
-- it works with 'ber' or 'yac' as well
-- 'like' instead of '=' works as well
select c from swedish where c = _latin1 'bar' collate latin1_german1_ci;
```

gives

```
+------+
| c    |
+------+
| Bar  |
| Bär  |
+------+
```

OK, works, that's all I need. but why?

IIRC `_latin1 'bar' collate latin1_german1_ci` is a [character set introducer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-introducer.html) which defines (forces?) the charset and collation of the string `'bar'`.
So I see two collates, swedish for the values of the column `c` and german1 for the search term.

What happens in the where clause? Has the selected string from column `c` collation `latin1_swedish_ci`? but then the comparison should give an error. Is it somehow converted to the collation `latin1_german1_ci`?

If I don't use the charset introducer the search with `'bar'` only gives `'bar'`, which (I think) is the expected behavior of the swedish collation.

Further on, if I do

```
select c from swedish where c = _latin1 'bär' collate latin1_german1_ci;
```

It gives 0 rows, why is that?

P.S.
I could not find any detailed documentation about the different collations, does anybody know where to find some info?

Comment: Any chance you are willing to switch to utf8mb4?

Comment: would that be for the table of for the charset introducer in the query?

Comment: If everything is utf8 (or utf8mb4), no introducer is needed.  Connection, byte encoding, column definition, html 'meta', etc.