# Illegal mix of collations - MySQL fake table

Tags: mysql, sql

I create a fake table by:

```
SELECT 'B' a_name UNION ALL  
SELECT 'A' a_name
```

and try to JOIN with different table but I see the error:

> illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci implicit) and
>   (utf8_general_ci coercible)

I am not the administrator so I am not able to update the table collation,

Is there any work-around for this problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41980698/mysql-select-with-different-collation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Troubleshooting "Illegal mix of collations" error in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029321/troubleshooting-illegal-mix-of-collations-error-in-mysql)

Comment: I changed that to `SELECT 'B' COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci AS a_name UNION ALL SELECT 'A' COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci AS  a_name` but now i see "COLLATION 'latin1_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8'"

Comment: is there any solution to that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like that your other (actual) table is using `utf8_general_ci`; while your database connection/server configuration is set for `latin1_swedish_ci`. It can be other way around too.

Nevertheless, we can use [`CONVERT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) function, to change the "fake table" to use `utf8` (if the other (actual) table is using `utf8`).

```
SELECT CONVERT('B' USING utf8) AS a_name UNION ALL  
SELECT CONVERT('A' USING utf8) AS a_name
```